# Swapping without using temporary variable not working in case of QuickSort [Java]

Tags: java, quicksort

I am using the following code to implement the QuickSort algorithm

```
public class QuickSort {

    int partition(int arr[], int low, int high) {
        //select last elem as pivot
        int pivot = arr[high];
        //init i as low - 1
        int i = low - 1;
        //GOAL : Shift all elem LT pivot to L and GT than pivot to R
        for (int j = low; j < high; j++) {
            if (arr[j] <= pivot) {
                i++;
                //swap a[i] & a[j]
                swap(arr, i, j);
            }
        }
        //swap i+1 elem with pivot
        swap(arr, i + 1, high);
        //i+1 is pos of partition
        return (i + 1);
    }

    void swap(int arr[], int i, int j) {
        //swap i & j elem of arr
        arr[i] = arr[i] ^ arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[i] ^ arr[j];
        arr[i] = arr[i] ^ arr[j];
    }

    void sort(int arr[], int low, int high) {
        if (low < high) {
            int pi = partition(arr, low, high);
            //sort L and R of pi
            sort(arr, low, pi - 1);
            sort(arr, pi + 1, high);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = {10, 7, 8, 9, 1, 5, 12, 4, 6};
        QuickSort quickSort = new QuickSort();
        quickSort.sort(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
        //print
        for (int i : arr) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

This gives the output `0 4 5 6 0 0 9 0 0` which is not correct. If I implement swapping using a temporary variable it gives the correct answer. If I implement swapping logic without a method, the code doesn't work..!!

If the input array is `{10, 7, 8, 9, 1, 5}`, I get the correct output. I tried to debug it and I observe that value gets changes to 0 upon swapping which is strange.

Comment: This method of swapping will not work if a==b

Comment: No matter what are the values in a and b it will always set a=b=0

Comment: Just take a pen and copy and solve the xor of a and b taking both of them equal and you will get it.

Comment: I've tried that. If I change swapping logic to using add and subtract method, it still fails..!!

Comment: Now could you tell me what is the new error or it is same as the previous one

Comment: `void swap(int arr[], int i, int j) {
        //swap i & j elem of arr
        arr[i] = arr[i] + arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[i] - arr[j];
        arr[i] = arr[i] - arr[j];
    }`   Using this swap method gives the same result as before i.e. `0 4 5 6 0 0 9 0 0`

Comment: Now its weird it should work, let me try your code

Comment: [Code on Online IDE](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/2nyJlVaC8n) when using +,- for swap logic with input `{10, 7, 8, 9, 1, 5, 12, 4, 6}`

Comment: The same code works with input `{10, 7, 8, 9, 1, 5}` as you can see [here](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/HID9Me33ZI)

Comment: Yes i am seeking that and wondering

Comment: If I do that using a temporary variable everything works like charm

Comment: also it is working for even number of numbers

Comment: Something wrong with logic it is working for even number of numbers but not for odd number of numbers.

Comment: ok in your swap method just add if(arr[i]==arr[j]) return and it will work